# Unable to determine hit limit quotas for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Can anyone verify the limit and quota numbers on free accounts for me? I've found 3 different mentions, that all seem to contradict with each other.

According to the [Google Analytics Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) it is 10M hits per month per account.

But in the [Google Developer Guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas) it specifies "10M hits per month per **property**." (emphasis not mine)

And finally, a [Data Limits support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en) is in itself conflicting stating that "If a property sends more hits per month to Analytics than allowed by the Analytics Terms of Service" and links to the Analytics ToS that specifies per account.

I currently have one property getting ~7.5M hits/mo and is the only property on the acct. I have more properties I'd like to add, but need to know if it will cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 10M hits/mo but for personal experience this is not a real limit. I have some propertys with over 200M hits/mo without 360 and nothing happen so far.

You should be fine for a while but its not a bad practice to audit the current state and evaluate if you might have unecessary events being tracked.

Hope it helps!